# I can't pass the code imacros to javascript

Tags: imacros

I use this code in imacros:

```
VERSION BUILD=8940826 RECORDER=FX
'TAB T=1
'TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !DATASOURCE C:\abc.txt
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 3
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!loop}}
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 120
URL GOTO=https://www.habbo.es/

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:EMAIL FORM=NAME:loginForm ATTR=NAME:email CONTENT={{!COL1}}
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:loginForm ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT={{!COL2}}

'Submit form
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:loginForm ATTR=TXT:Conectar
WAIT SECONDS=3
```

But when i pass this code to javascript the col1 doesn't work and doesn't do the job. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please consider adding a question to your post. Simply saying it doesn't work makes the question difficult to answer specifically.

Comment: works now and sorry before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JS this code

```
SET !DATASOURCE C:\abc.txt
```

is written like this

```
SET !DATASOURCE C:\\abc.txt
```

Comment: OMG WORKS FINE YOU ARE A GOD! THANKS SO MUCH I LOV YOU OKS THANX SO MUCH FRIEND

Comment: @OmarAlami please be sure to check this as your answer and upvote.